Как объединить ячейки в каждом столбце в Google Docs через app script
Не получается объединить пустые ячейки в каждом столбце с ячейкой, в которой есть значение.
const dataRow = table.appendTableRow();
dataRow.appendTableCell(basis + '\n' + nomer); // "Основание для проведения работ"
dataRow.appendTableCell(firstEvent.trimEnd()); // "Наименование мероприятий"
dataRow.appendTableCell(firstQuantity.toString()); // "Шт/м"
dataRow.appendTableCell(location); // "Место проведения работ"
dataRow.appendTableCell(formattedDate); // "Срок выполнения"

eventsArray.forEach((event, index) => {
const newRow = table.appendTableRow();
newRow.appendTableCell(''); // Пустая ячейка для "Основания"
newRow.appendTableCell(event.trimEnd().replace(/—\\s*/, '')); // Добавляем мероприятие в новую ячейку
const quantityValue = quantitiesArray[index]; // Берем следующее значение для "Шт/м"
newRow.appendTableCell(quantityValue !== undefined ? quantityValue.toString() : ''); // Заполняем "Шт/м" или оставляем пустым
newRow.appendTableCell(''); // Пустая ячейка для "Место проведения работ"
newRow.appendTableCell(''); // Пустая ячейка для "Срок выполнения"

с помощью Merge не работает(т.к. не поддерживается в гугл доке)
Где в ячейке имеется 1 значение, эти столбцы должны быть объединены в 1 ячейку с этим же значением
Результат должен быть таким(добавлено вручную, надо написать с помощью кода):

Не совсем понятно, что и с чем нужно объединить... В таблицах в гугл документах есть функция merge()

Добавил как должен выглядеть результат

У меня не получилось объединить с помощью merge, может я что-то делаю не так... Но постоянно выходит ошибка, либо при объединении пропадает ячейка(становится пустое место)
